# How to custom a sortable table with custom query in dashboard of ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Let's say I have a ActiveRecord query:

```
User.select('name', 'created_at').all
=> [#<User created_at: "2012-08-06 13:27:40", name: "Alice">, #<User created_at: "2012-08-06 15:41:33", name: "Bill">]
```

How to display a sortable table with rowspan by `created_at` column?

Expected output html:

```
   <table>
      <tr>
          <th>created_at</th>
          <td>name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>2012-08-06</td>
          <td>Alice</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>2012-08-06</td>
          <td>Bill</td>
      </tr>   
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation: http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html

Assuming you are using the last version (0.5.1):

```
index do
  column "created_at", :sortable => :created_at do |user|
    user.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # if the format is different that expected
  end
  column "name", :sortable => :name do |user|
    user.name
  end
end
```